# Illegal character- Try using extended mode if you need to encode the full ASCII character set

Tags: java, barcode, barbecue

I am unable to generate barcode(code39) for 'space' character.
For example: "BAR CODE"
I am passing it with = or _ or ~ symbols like below
BAR_CODE
BAR=CODE 
BAR~CODE

For all the above, getting an error as "Illegal character- Try using extended mode if you need to encode the full ASCII character set"
[image: Image of a stack trace]
Can you please suggest this.

Thanks& Regards,
Ashok.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39 the space is a legal character. The other symbols you try aren't.

Comment: Symbols `=`, `_`, and `~` are illegal in Code39, but space should work.  Are you sure you use plain ASCII space, not one of Unitcode white space characters such as non-breakable space or figure space?

Comment: Be sure you are using UTF-8 and not UTF-16 for input.

Comment: Yes, the space is  a legal character in code39. But I have tried with "BAR CODE" , it is encoding(using barbecue open source java library) for BAR only in pdf file.

Comment: If I Print BarCode for "BAR CODE" in pdf, problem exists.We are getting correct BarCode if i print it in html page. Any Idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, calling `.ToUpper()` on the barcode text, solved the problem.